# Does Daze setup the conditions for a rogue's sneak attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue

Does the 0-level wizard/sorceror *Daze* spell, if successfully cast, setup the conditions for a rogue's *sneak attack*? Pondering the *minor magic* rogue talent and *Daze* would be useful early game if this can work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No, Daze does not enable sneak attack.

From the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/daze), on the Daze spell (*emphasis mine*):

> This spell clouds the mind of a humanoid creature with 4 or fewer Hit Dice so that it takes no actions. Humanoids of 5 or more HD are not affected. *A dazed subject is not stunned, so attackers get no special advantage against it.*

From the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Dazed), on the Dazed condition (*emphasis mine*):

> The creature is unable to act normally. A dazed creature can take no actions, but *has no penalty to AC.*

From the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue), on sneak attacks (*emphasis mine*):

> The rogue’s attack deals extra damage *anytime her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not)*, or when the rogue flanks her target.

The Daze spell inflicts the dazed condition. Neither of those things cause any sort of AC penalty, and therefore they do not enable a rogue ally to sneak attack the target.

Comment: Great, thanks. Been playing AD&D since the late 70s, new to PF. Thanks for the link to the PFSRD!  The text there is different than the text for the Daze spell in the Core Rulebook but on closer reading of the book I agree. Actually I will have to look for that condition listing in the Rulebook.

Answer (score 4):

### It does not

The [Daze](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/daze/) spell simply makes the target, if unsucessful on their saving throw, to lose their next action. That is the effect of the [dazed condition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Dazed):

> The creature is unable to act normally. A dazed creature can take no actions, but has no penalty to AC. A dazed condition typically lasts 1 round.

For a rogue's [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Rogue/#TOC-Sneak-Attack) to work, you normally need one of the following conditions:

- Target must be [flanked](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Flanking) (happens if the rogue and an ally are on opposite sides of an enemy);
- Target must be denied their dexterity bonus to AC, which happens on the following situations:

  - Target is [flat-footed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Flat-Footed) (happens if they haven't acted yet in combat);
  - The rogue has total concealment, such as from being [invisible](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Invisible) or undetected by the target (see [stealth](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth/) and [blinded](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Blinded));
  - Target is [climbing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/climb/) or [balancing on a surface](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics/);
  - Target is either [stunned](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Stunned), [pinned](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Pinned), [running](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Run), [squeezing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Squeezing), [paralyzed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Paralyzed), or [helpless](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Helpless);
  - Target is "off balance" by failing a swim check (see [aquatic terrain rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain/));

Since *dazed* doesn't deny the target their AC bonus, nor it grants any benefit to sneak attacks specifically, it doesn't allow the rogue to sneak attack.