# Glamered Weapons and Flat Footedness

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have recently created a spear wielder for a one shot game and I was thinking of making a rogue with a [glamered](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/glamered/) spear whom she will make her spear look like something that does not have the reach quality.

> A glamered weapon can be commanded to change its shape and appearance to assume the form of another object of similar size. The weapon retains all its properties (including weight) when so disguised but does not radiate magic

According to this text the weapon still holds the reach property so would the weapon allow the user to catch someone flat footed as the enemy will not see the true form of the weapon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, the weapon itself is unable to apply the flat footed condition or deny dexterity

> The weapon retains all its properties (including weight) when so disguised but does not radiate magic.

This does not add an additional mechanic of applying the flat footed condition or denying dexterity bonuses to AC.  So Rules as written it does not.

It does allow you to approach you DM with requesting circumstance modifiers to the role (possible advantage).  But this will be a DM / situational specific ruling.

There is an argument to be made that you might have advantage on the first attack you make against that creature.  An a sense motive check VS your bluff deception check to notice if something was amiss.

It is also arguable that it could contribute to gaining surprise on the monster in the event you use a "Diplomatic Ambush" type strategy to initiate combat (normal surprise rules apply).  You approach diplomatically, then start combat out of the blue, and since your weapon is glammored you have a chance to catch them off guard (your not 'armed').  "Hey... I'm going up to the town guard with this broom...."

Comment: Being denied your Dexterity bonus doesn't make you Flat-Footed, its the other way around.

Comment: Flat-footed in Pathfinder is a simple condition: *Have you acted in combat yet?* No? Then you are flat-footed. Being **denied the dex bonus to ac** is another condition. Check [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131111/21153) for a simple list of things that will cause you to lose your dex bonus to ac.

Comment: Edited appropriately.   The character in question said they were a rouge, so I tailored the question to address his sneak attack fishing without realizing it.   Good catch.

Answer (score 9):

The basic [Spear](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spear) doesn't have reach but the [Longspear](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longspear) does. However, the Longspear is 8 feet long (about 2,5 meters and 1,5 x regular human height), and the glamered version would  "assume the form of another object of similar size", and still be very long.

Also, note that the longspear will physically have an other shape rather than just a disguise, so its "collision box" and its "3D model" will be the same. No hitting further than it looks it could, unlike an invisible blade.

Your opponent wouldn't be surprised by the reach of your weapon.

Comment: Yeah, since the *glamered* weapon can "change its shape and appearance," that means hitting a dude with a *+1 glamered longspear* while it has the shape and appearance of a ladder is just like hitting a dude with a *+1 ladder.* That may be *rude*, but it wouldn't be a *surprise.*